# can't find my server's private IP address

Tags: ip-address

I have two CentOS 5 servers, one for database and one for the code.

The problem is I can't find my ipaddress for my database server. When I type ifconfig it says:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:48:BD:B9:91
          inet addr:115.84.182.205  Bcast:115.84.182.255  Mask:255.255.255.192
```

I can't find my internal Ipaddress anywhere. When I trying to connect by its public Ipaddress, the wait percentage of CPU is too high (about 25%).

Can you please tell me how to work it out? Do I need to purchase a new NIC?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by internal ip address?? You can only assign one IP per NIC card and seems like you have assigned it public IP "115.84.182.205".

Comment: Tayyab, you can assign virtual IP addresses to the card (see virtual interfaces for reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question actually belongs to ServerFault.

A server does not necessarily have any "internal" address, so I assume you just have to use the public IP of your server. I also don't see any reason why the CPU wait would increase when you use a "public IP" instead of a "internal IP" (note the quotes? There's no real difference between those address ranges/types)

Comment: Thank you, I see. But why my mysql-server responds very slow and the %wait is quite high? Do I need to do some configuration? Thanks for your support.

Comment: It's hard to say without more details. Is there a router between your server and the client machine? What kind of router? If it's a low-end consumer router, they're not meant to route between LANs.